# SharedPreferences.getAll() does not have preference keys that are false. How to retrieve all keys?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

Only CheckboxPreference keys with a android:defaultValue="true" will be shown in the code below. So none of the keys with defaultValue="false" are shown. **How do I get a list of all the keys in my preference file then?**

```
  PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,R.xml.settings,true); //readAgain=false is same result
        SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Map<String, ?> prefMap=prefs.getAll();
         for(String key:prefMap.keySet()) {
             Log.d("preference key=",key); //only keys with true are shown
         }
    }
```

According to the docs getAll() should: "Retrieve all values from the preferences." However it appears to only get the keys that have default=true unless the preference has been set later by the user.

**EDIT: [This is likely related to Android Bug: 6441](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6641), but doesn't give me a workaround to get all the keys.**

Comment: If it doesn't have a default value and no user value then it's not in the shared preferences. if you want all defined preferences, maybe you should iterate your preferences xml file.

Comment: @Ran->These preferences have android:defaultValue=false, so that is a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all preferences with the following (I use it to enable/disable all preferences):

```
    final ListAdapter adapter = getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter();
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        Object object = adapter.getItem(i);
        if(object instanceof Preference){
            ((Preference)object).setEnabled(state);  // state -> my own variable
        } 
    }
```